# New line on septic character

Tags: php

Noob question

I have a text file that I read using php. This is an example of the text line.

*News.com | LIVE: 'Whatever happens today, history will judge them' - Mayor in trouble!.*

```
<?php
 $lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('rss.txt'));
 $line = $lines[mt_rand(0, count($lines) - 1)];
 list($title, $description) = explode('|',$line);
?>
 <?php echo $title; ?><br>
 <?php echo $description; ?>
```

This displays as:

```
News.com
LIVE: 'Whatever happens today, history will judge them' - Mayor in trouble!
```

How do I create a new line at the "-" so that it looks like this:

```
News.com
LIVE: 'Whatever happens today, history will judge them'
Mayor in trouble!
```

Comment: What you did to `$line` you can do again to `$description`. You explode by `' - '` (notice the spaces) and then loop over the results

Comment: or you could just `str_replace(" - ", "\n", $line)`

Comment: @CD001 yes, that would work too :)

Comment: `str_replace($line, " - ", "<br>")` perhaps

Comment: Yes, thanks. Also using this function works: https://phpdevtips.com/2011/07/exploding-a-string-using-multiple-delimiters-using-php/

Answer (score 1):

By seperating at the "-".

```
$twoParts = explode("-",$description);
echo $twoParts[0]."<br />".$twoParts[1];
```

or using str_replace()

```
str_replace($description, " - ", "<br>");
```